# What does it mean when a project fails to load in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was trying to load my project up to work on it and I was seeing Load Failed next to the name of the project in parenthesis.  Also I am not able to add new items to the project via the Project menu.  Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it squarely belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the path of your project has changed or similar. For example, you've moved the project into another location.

Verify the original files are there on your machine. If you select the missing project, and open properties, it will show you where it thinks the file should be (under Project File and Project Folder).

You can right click and re-load I think, or, remove the project and re-add it to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Visual Studio. There are numerous fixes but none of them work consistently.

I have encountered it as a result of various use cases at various times.  Sometimes it simply goes away on its own without any intervention. Then again, sometimes not. If you are upgrading the project to a newer tool set then it might help to edit the project file to use the new tool set manually and then reload.

Comment: Can you also point to a resource that confirms this is a bug.